# Find distinct values of a column and also number of objects per distinct value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a Mongo collection which has thousands of entries , there is a field in every entry called "month", I need to find distinct values of month as well as the count of  entries per distinct "month". 
Document looks like this:
    {
        "status": "REJECTED",
        "month": "JAN",
        "id": "25"
    }

I am using aggregation with the following pipeline:

```
{
    "$group": {
        _id: { status: "$status" }, 
        "months": { "$addToSet": "$month" }
    } 
}
```

So I want result to be something like the following

{
    "JAN": 5,
    "FEB": 0
}
OR
array of distinct months and array of respective counts.

Comment: Can you update your question with some sample documents and your expected JSON output?

Comment: Have you tried something like `{     "$group": {         _id: "$month" , "count": { "$sum": 1 } } }` ?

Comment: @Veeram Yes i tried it but it will give count of all the documents, but i want count of documents "month" wise.

Comment: It is  grouped by month so it should give monthly count. Can you show me your query ?

Comment: @Veeram This query works for me fine { "$group": { _id: "$month" , "count": { "$sum": 1 }, "months": {"$addToSet": "$month"} } } - It returns - [{"_id":"JAN","count":1,"month":["JAN"]},{"_id":"FEB","count":2,"month":["FEB"]}]    -Thanks